# Power analysis for AB testing-- multiple variants

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-power, ab-test

I'd like to do an experiment that is basically an A/B test with about 10 different conditions. A single trial results in either success or failure. The null hypothesis is that all of the conditions have the same success rate.  I'm trying to figure out how many trials I need to collect for each condition.

Would it be valid for me to run a series of simulations where I draw 10 values from a beta distribution (to represent the probability of success for each of the conditions), and then calculate the difference between the mean success rate of the 'winner' for each simulation, and the mean success rate for the other conditions. This should give me an idea of 
the size of difference I can detect as a function of the number of trials.

Is there some specific power analysis I should be doing instead?  Like a power analysis for a chi-square test?  But I'm not sure a chi-square test is addressing the issue at hand (aka, is the best condition significantly better than the mean).

Thanks!